# Nginx proxy for node.js app error: Failed to load resource

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I have two node.js apps: one is my site and second is CI tool. I have the following nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
    }

    location /ci {
        rewrite ^/ci(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    }
}
```

When i open example.com in browser it loads all resources requested by index.html correctly, but when i open example.com/ci it loads only index.html and i got errors like these:

```
GET http://example.com/styles/styles.css     404
GET http://example.com/scripts/app.js        404
```

I have added `<base href="/ci">` into head of index.html in my CI app, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with next nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        if ($http_referer ~* example.com/ci) {
            rewrite (.*) http://example.com/ci$1;
        }

        access_log off;

        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_buffering   off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location = /ci { rewrite ^ /ci/ last; }
    location /ci/ {
        access_log off;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_buffering   off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Also on the client side of my CI app i specified domain and port for socket.io connection: `io.connect('http://example.com:3000')`.
No `<base>` html tags needed.

Comment: With this config all POST requests from http://example.com/ci will be turned to GET and i can't figure out how to fix this.